# Iframe not loading in IE after installing update KB3154070

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe

We have an application that mostly deals with iframes (loads the different pages within the application on demand)

Recently, the IE browser got updated with [KB3154070](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3154070)(Current IE Version: 11.0.9600.18314) as part of the system updates. After that update, majority of the functionality is breaking completely. It effected all the pages that use iframes. The content is not loading and resulting in a blank page. The request appears to be aborted when inspected in the network panel as shown in the below screen capture.
[Network Traffic Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKfgp.png)

We have performed the following troubleshooting

We made sure that all iframe tags are close properly.
The src of the iframe is not empty.
If we access the same page outside (without loading into iframe), it works fine. But, the problem is with only within iframe.
As a quick workaround to this problem, we have asked our users to roll back the update. But, this is not the expected solution.

Your help is really appreciated.

Regards,
Swajay.

Comment: add : <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />  to header, it will force to IE 10 mode. also try to clear Temporary Internet files, Cookies and History

Comment: From my experimentation, it appears to be a problem in iframe handling when IE is compatibility mode.  MS changed something in how iframe is loaded.  As suggested by Matt, it could be a DOM moving issue.  Previously, IE would not destroy an recreate an iframe when moved in compat mode (it does in standards/edge mode). If this is now the case in compat, this can break a lot of legacy apps. I have observed that zone setting changes can sometimes make things still work, but it is unreliable. I venture MS introduced a race condition in compat iframe support.

Comment: This is not limited to the update in the title. As of June 15, 2016, the latest update also exhibits this problem.

Answer (score 10):

@Matt's answer provides a clue on how to workaround the problem.  It appears that IE, with the KB3154070 installed, blocks iframe content if the iframe initiates any scripting operations before the parent DOM tree is ready.  I have noticed no blocking occurs if resource loaded by iframe contains no scripting.  I have also noticed that sometimes IE will not block content with scripting, but this is likely due to a race condition between parent DOM being ready and iframe resource loading.

Another observation is I have not seen any iframe loading problems when running IE in edge mode.  It appears the problem only occurs when running in compatibility mode.

To workaround the problem for the project I work on, I stubbed the iframe, where I declare no value for the src attribute.  In the main page's onload handler--which indicates the DOM tree is ready--I use javascript to set the src attribute of the iframe.  Doing this appears to work, where the iframe gets properly loaded.

For example, say you have the following:

```
<iframe id="myIFrame"></iframe>
```

In your onload handler, you have something like:

```
document.getElementById('myIFrame').src = '/whatever/url/to/load';
```

I still think KB3154070 introduced a regression bug (if not bugs), but maybe what I have suggested can be applied to your application.

**UPDATE**

IE update [KB317016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3170106) appears to fix the iframe loading problem. Microsoft has officially recognized the bug: [KB3176757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176757).

I plan on keeping my changes in place since some of our customers may not be able to update IE immediately. Also, the changes made still work in all versions of IE we need to support.

Comment: Until this moment, your suggestion was the only thing that really worked.

Answer (score 4):

We ran into exactly the same problem. The issue in our specific case was that iframes now abort their requests when they are re-parented (i.e. moved from one DOM tree location to another). We were able to work around the new restriction by avoiding moving the iframe while it was loading. I can't be certain that's exactly what's happening in your case, but I'd wager it was some interaction occurring between the start of the iframe load and its completion.

Comment: I think you are on to something. In my testing, I discovered that if the iframe attempts to invoke any scripting (e.g. trying to load dojo.js with a script tag), IE would "block" it, causing the body of the iframe to not exist. I am currently seeing some success by stubbing the iframe with no src attribute value. Then in the main document onload handler, I use javascript to set the iframe src. This seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

My company legacy software was hugely impacted by this issue. We came up with the following generic solution until microsoft solves this bug:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    loadIframesIE();
 });

 function loadIframesIE() {
    var $iframe;
    $('iframe').each(function(cnt, iframe) {
        $iframe = $(iframe);

        // If the iframe body has no child, it couldn't be loaded
        if ($iframe.contents().find('body').children().length === 0 && !$iframe.attr('resetted')) {

            // Necessary to avoid an infinite loop in some cases
            $iframe.attr('resetted', true);
            $iframe.attr('src', $iframe.attr('src'));

        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed in my case by setting the compatibility header to Edge. With KB3154070, it doesn't work for Document Modes 7 and 8, but it works for 9, 10 and Edge.

Also, the @ewh suggestion to set src after document load worked ok. Thanks.